# PDO - configuration, database connection & and using

Tags: php, pdo

I'm currently reading a book and watching some tutorials about PHP with MySQL (PDO), but it is not clear where to put certain things - where to put some code, should I put the connection to the database within try-catch and so on.

So, I'll explain how I started my project and if you could tell me if this is wrong or is there a better way.

1. In the directory *includes* I have **config.php**:

   ```
   <?php 
   defined('DB_DNS') ? null : define("DB_DNS", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=photo_gallery");
   defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "root");
   defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "");
   ```
2. In the directory *includes* I have **database.php**:

   ```
    try {
      $connection= new PDO(DB_DNS, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
      $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
       echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
       die();
    }
   ```
3. In the directory *includes* I have **user.php** with a class named **User**:

   ```
    <?php

    require_once(__DIR__."/../includes/config.php");
    require_once(__DIR__."/../includes/database.php");

    class User
    {
      public function findAllUsers() {
         try {
           global $connection;
           $sql = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
           $result = $sql->execute();
           return $result;
         } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            die();
         }
      }
      public function find_by_id($id = 0) {
         try {
           global $connection;
           $sql = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id");
           $result = $sql->execute(array($id));
           return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
           echo $e->getMessage();
           die();
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Similar to this, some authors do tutorials and courses that I watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok there are three distinct parts I'll discuss, but the most important one is the last one (the `User` class).

#### Config constants:

```
defined('DB_DNS') ? null : define("DB_DNS", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=photo_gallery");
defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "root");
```

Things like this are sadly quite common. The problem with this setup is that things like username, password and even the default DB name (owing to it being part of the DSN) are all hard-coded in your project. The chances of these credentials being tracked by a SVC system like git are really quite high. As are the chances that the credentials may vary depending on the environment the code runs on (local/develop/testing/production). These are configuration parameters that you really shouldn't keep hard-coded in the code base

All things aside, it's also a lot shorter to write:

```
defined('SOME_CONSTANT') || define('SOME_CONSTANT', 'define here');
```

You're using a ternary to set a given value to `null`. Now a DSN can't be `null`, nor can the DB username. You should error in those cases, instead of setting the values to `null`.

#### try-catch-die

Code like this:

```
try {
    $connection= new PDO(DB_DNS, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

is again all too common. But it's smelly for a number of reasons:

- `Exception`'s indicate something *Exceptional* has happened, and requires special attention by a piece of code written especially for such an event, often this is an Exception-handler. A basic handler will check some parameters to see if it can/should output details about the error, or hide them from the client, and will almost always write the full stack trace to some log, so you can diagnose the problem later on. What you're doing here is squelching that information, echo an often cryptic error message and then `die`. That's not *handling* the exception, that's giving up
- `PDO` never throws a *"regular"* `Exception` instance, it throws `PDOExceptions`, your catch block should reflect this. This becomes especially useful when you're working on larger projects where a single method call can throw any number of different exceptions, and your calling it from a place where you can handle some of these exceptions, but can't handle others. In that case, you'll write something like `catch (ExceptionICanHandle $e) {}` and let other exceptions propagate to code that *can* handle it
- Your DSN string is missing the `;charset=utf8` bit at the end (required to [protect against injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/1230836))
- You're calling `setAttribute` after constructing the instance. You needn't do that, the `PDO` constructor takes a fourth argument (array of attributes).

In short, here's what I'd write:

```
//parse or "obtain" config in some way
$dsn .= ';charset=utf8';//in case the charset is still missing, fix the config. I'm adding it here as a reminder
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
```

No try-catch nonsense, no `die` and no `setAttribute`. Just 1 line that does it all.

#### The `User` class

Your class suffers from a number of issues. The short list:

- `global` is code-smell, a sign of bad design. Don't use it unless you really have to. And you really never need to use it (I've not seen a valid use case in 10 years +)
- Again: try-catch-die, I've explained what is wrong with this
- `echo` in a method is code-smell: SRP (Single Responsability Principle) is one of the core principles to follow if you want to write good code: A class should have only one job. `User` is a data object, it represents a DB record that represents a user of sorts. That's its job, nothing more, nothing less. Taking care of output is the job of a template/view.
- Coding standards are important. Your class does not conform to the most widely [adopted standard: PHP-FIG (PSR)](http://php-fig.org)
- This is perhaps personal, but for the same reasons (SRP), I don't like data models to have `find` or `save` methods defined. That's the job of a DB mapper, or in doctrine-speak, an entity manager. Still, it's not unheard of to have data models with DB connections, so this is just a matter of opinion

In short, and assuming you're to keep the `find_by_id` method, here's what I'd have the `User` class look like:

```
class User
{//next line <-- PSR
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    protected $connection = null;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $statments = [];

    /**
     * @param PDO $connection
     */
    public function __construct(PDO $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function findById($id)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($id) || $id < 1) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('ID must be positive integer');
        }
        $method = __METHOD__;
        if (!isset($this->statements[$method])) {
            $this->statements[$method] = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :id');
        }
        $stmt = $this->statements[$method];
        $stmt->execute([':id' => $id]);
        $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        if (!$data) {
            return null;
        }
        $found = new User($this->connection);//pass connection
        //load data model
        $found->setId($data['id'])
            ->setName($data['name']);
        return $found;
    }
}
```

The other method, I'd write in the same way, but I'll leave that for you to write. I'll have a look to previous reviews I've posted here that do roughly the same thing (query the DB, setup a data model etc...), because this review was written in a hurry, the code is not tested, and I might have left some things out

## [related review - links to 4 other reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59095/16133)

Comment: First of all - thank you Elias for all this. Lets start with **config.php**:  You wrote that tings like username, pass andso on... should not be hard-coded in my project. Can you give me an example of config.php or just explain to me where would you have those things (user, pass), how would it look in real world example? Sorry for my bad English.  **As for the other (particularly the part relating to the class User) - there're few new things that I have not seen before, so tomorrow I'll answer / comment those parts of code (need to google some things and read what they do).**  Again, thank you

Comment: @PeraMika: Configuration is best kept in a data file-format of choice (ini, yaml, json or XML files. Those files should then be read/parsed/loaded into a data structure (most commonly a class) that holds all config parameters that you can access along these lines: `$config->get('dsn');`

Comment: I just tested this code and there is `Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::setId()  ..... `         But, before that I want to ask you why use `$method = __METHOD__; .... `, why not just `$stmt = $this->connection->prepare(...)`?

Comment: Also, I don't understand this part with `$found` (_//pass connection_ and _//load data model_) - Why you didn't just `return $data;`, why did you _pass the connection_ and _load data model_ ? and then `return $found;`

Comment: @PeraMika: I'm passing the connection because, in its current form, the `User` class has to have a `PDO` instance passed to its connection. I'm also returning an instance of `User` instead of the array `$data` because that's what I'd expect a method called `User::findById` to return: a _User_, not an array of data. It makes the whole code truly object oriented: calling methods that return the requested data in a normalized form (ie an object), which can be passed to other methods that can then type-hint: `public function updateUser(User $user, array $data)`

Comment: As for the fatal error: The code I posted here is incomplete. You'll have to declare properties for each field in the user table (id, email, name, etc...), and have a getter and a setter for each of these properties (check one of the linked reviews, there is bound to be a more complete example in one of them). I'm using `__METHOD__` to create a unique key so I don't have to call `PDO::prepare` each time `User::findById` is called. I can re-use the prepared statement if I've already created it. It's a basic way of saving on repeated `prepare` calls

Comment: is it ok that instead of creating a new instance `$found` - we use $this and after setting values - just return it: `$this->setId($data['id']); $this->setUsername($data['username']); return $this;` ?

Comment: @PeraMika That would be fine, but in that case I'd change the method name from `findById` to `loadUserById($id)`, because I'd expect a `find` method to return what it finds, `null` if nothing was found. If you want to populate the current instance, that's fine but think about how you handle an empty result-set: realisticly, the only thing you _can_ do is throw an exception. If you don't, you have to hope the caller will bother to check if `$user->loadById(1);` actually set the properties correctly. Something that  gets even harder if `$user` wasn't empty to begin with...

Comment: You wrote about calling methods that should return the requested data in a normalized form (ie an object) - what should we return in case of finding all users (`SELECT * FROM users`) - should we return $stmt->execute(); or return fetchAll or return an array of User objects? Or maybe Fetching into a class?

Comment: @PeraMika: That method should indeed return an array of `User` instances. using PDO's `FETCH_CLASS` is something I generally advice against. It actually bypasses the constructor, or any getters/setters you may define. It assigns the class' properties directly, bypassing any code that validates/filters/formats the data itself. Besides: all you really need to do is write a simple loop, that's not that hard

Comment: In class User - do you recommend to create a method for every type of CRUD which refers to a table users in database? For example - to Insert a new user in database, to Update, to Delete... ? If yes, are there cases in which I'll have a some SQL that relates to a table users - but I do not need to create a method for that in class User?

Comment: @PeraMika: It's quite common to see models implement a `save`/`update` method that handles the `INSERT` queries ([propel](http://propelorm.org/) does something similar - but it's a bit more clever). I personally don't like that type of design, because I feel it violates the SRP: a model either represents data, or handles DB interaction. Having a `save` method on a data model means your model does both... I mentioned this as being, perhaps, a matter of personal taste, though